# How to access Lambda environment variable?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, aws-lambda

When running a .net core 2.1 AWS Lambda function, it is simple to fetch an environment variable from the AWS Lambda Console in c# using:

```
var envVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myVariableName");
```

However, when running ASP.NET core 2.1 as a Serverless Application on AWS Lambda, this does not work (the above returns null).

I can set a *local* env variable in the launchSettings.json file, but I want to use the Env variable from the AWS Lambda console.

How can I access the AWS Lambda Env variable in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Comment: did you set the variable in the `serverless.template` file?

Comment: environment variables are set as port of the deployment. make sure you added the variable as part of the environment.

Comment: Nope.  That is what I missed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> How can I access the AWS Lambda Env variable in ASP.NET Core 2.1

You access it the same way you would as before.

```
var envVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myVariableName");
```

Ensure that the environment variable is set for the respective resource so that it is available when called.

Each resource would have an entry in the *serverless.template* file, which is the AWS CloudFormation template used to deploy functions.

Environment variable entries are found under the `Resources:{ResourceName}:Properties:Environment:Variables` JSON path in the file.

Example declaration

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Transform" : "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description" : "An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
  "Parameters" : {
  },
  "Conditions" : {
  },
  "Resources" : {
    "Get" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "TimeZoneService::TimeZoneService.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore1.0",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 60,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [ "AWSLambdaFullAccess" ],
        "Environment" : {
          "Variables" : {
            "myVariableName" : "my environment variable value"
          }
        },
        "Events": {
          "PutResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs" : {
  }
}
```

Reference [Build and Test a Serverless Application with AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-build-test-severless-app.html#examine-the-files-in-the-serverless-application)

Reference [Creating a Serverless Application with ASP.NET Core, AWS Lambda and AWS API Gateway](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnet-core-aws-lambda-serverless-application/)

Comment: Don't forget that you can treat environment variables as a configuration source, and never use this syntax at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public interface IEnviromentVariables {
    string getEnVariable(string variable);
}

public class EnviromentClass : IEnviromentVariables {
    public string getEnVariable(string variable) {
        return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(variable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this when .net provides you that out of the box?